# python - Program to count a set of continous letters in a string failing

Tags: python, string

I want to calculate the number of times 'bob' occurs in the string s. The code that i have written is:

```
s = 'qwbobthghdeerxybobhjkhgkjgbob'
num = 0
count = 0
for char in s:
     if char == 'b':
         letter = s[num+1]
         if letter == 'o':
             letter = s[num+2]
             if letter == 'b':
                     count = count + 1
     num += 1   
print('Number of times bob occurs is:' + str(count))
```

Running the code gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/practice.py", line 6, in <module>
    letter = s[num+1]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

The value of variable num in shell comes out as

```
>>>num
28
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

It's easier with built-in function [count](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count):

```
s = 'qwbobthghdeerxybobhjkhgkjgbob'
s.count('bob')
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, count gives you the answer.

The problem with your code giving index out of range is because when it reaches the last "b" in the string s, this code:

```
letter = s[num+1]
```

attempts

```
letter = s[28+1]
```

which gives you

```
letter = s[29]
```

and hence the exception occurs.

A simple fix would be to stop checking once there is less than 3 characters left in the string.

Answer (score 2):

count method returns of how many times obj occurs in a variable.

s = 'qwbobthghdeerxybobhjkhgkjgbob'

print s.count('bob')